# Vue Router: Keep query parameter and use same view for children

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm rewriting an existing Angular 1 application with Vue.

The application *always* needs to authenticate an user by `locale`, `id` and `token` before entering any views. Respecting the conventions of our API, I specified the `token` as a query parameter within my main parent route.

Coming from the existing Angular's UI router implementation I thought this is the way to go:

```js
// main.js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<router-view name="main"></router-view>'
})

// router.js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'start',
      path : '/:locale/:id', // /:locale/:id?token didn't work
      query: {
        token: null
      },
      beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
        // 1. Get data from API via locale, id and token
        // 2. Update store with user data
      },
      components: {
        main: startComponent
      },
      children: [{
        name: 'profile',
        path: 'profile',
        components: {
          main: profileComponent
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
})
```

When I navigate to the `profile` view, I expect the view to change and the query token to stay, e.g. `/en-US/123?token=abc` to `/en-US/123/profile?token=abc`. Neither happens.

I'm using Vue 2.3.3 and Vue Router 2.3.1.

Questions:

- Can I keep query parameters when navigating to child routes?
- Am I using the Vue router right here? Or do I need to blame my UI router bias?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can resolve this in the global hooks of Router

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';

const Router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
});

function hasQueryParams(route) {
  return !!Object.keys(route.query).length
}

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if(!hasQueryParams(to) && hasQueryParams(from)){
    next({name: to.name, query: from.query});
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

If the new route (`to`) does not have its own parameters, then they will be taken from the previous route (`from`)

Comment: Actually using `toWithQuery = Object.assign({}, to, {query: from.query});next(toWithQuery);` is more robust

Comment: @oliverpool +1, I had troubles with going back to the root page without this. p.s. this looks like one of ways to handle localization so I'm surprised there isn't so much more to read about this use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! More note to that is `next()` must be the last navigation call for Vue Router to know when should it stop going to the next page.

Comment: I have optional dynamic routes so my routing chokes on this when there are params. This works though: `next({ ...to, query: from.query });`

Comment: What to do if you need to erase query? This solution is bugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can add in a `mounted` hook a router navigation guard `beforeEach` like this `preserveQueryParams`:

```js
// helpers.js
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

const preserveQueryParams = (to, from, next) => {
  const usePreviousQueryParams = isEmpty(to.query) && !isEmpty(from.query);
  if (usePreviousQueryParams) {
    next({ ...to, query: from.query });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

```js
// StartComponent.vue
removeBeforeEachRouteGuard: Function;

mounted() {
  this.removeBeforeEachRouteGuard = this.$router.beforeEach(preserveQueryParams);
}

// don't forget to remove created guard
destroyed() {
  this.removeBeforeEachRouteGuard();
  // resetting query can be useful too
  this.$router.push({ query: undefined });
}
```

Comment: executing `next({ ...to })` fails for me with a warning from Vue Router: Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from .. to ...