# Appending specific query-params from prev route to new route in Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router

While passing query-params from prev route to new route via beforeEach nav-guards,
facing the following inifinite loop error
`Detected an infinite redirection in a navigation guard`

Requirement:
For any given valid route in Vue App, when a query-param is passed to it
(Eg: yoursite/landingpage/?displayNav=true)
Subsequent route changes should persist the above query-param

Using `"vue-router": "^4.1.6"`

As this needs to be achieved for all valid routes in the Vue App,
Followed the navigation-guards approach by utilising beforeEach
Here's a code-block which intercepts every route change and appends displayNav if present

```
// guards.js
export const appendQueryParamsToRoute = (to, from, next) => {
  const query = Object.assign({}, to.query)

  // Check if the displayNav param exists in the previous route's query params
  if (from.query['displayNav']) {
    query['displayNav'] = 'true'
  }

  next({
    path: to.path,
    query
  })
}
```

```
// router.js
router.beforeEach(appendQueryParamsToRoute)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. Your error might come from query conflicts. You could try validating the query params from both directions first and then pass them along:

```
// guards.js
export const persistRouteQuery = (to, from, next) => {
    const query = { ...to.query, ...from.query }

    if (!Object.keys(to.query).length && Object.keys(from.query).length) {
        next({ ...to, query })
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

// router.js
router.beforeEach(persistRouteQuery)
```

Heres a more robust solution based on the previous code and your example that passes along only explicitly defined route queries:

```
// guards.js
const persistentQueries = ['displayNav']

const hasQuery = (route, queryKeys = [])=> {
    const keys = Object.keys(route.query)
    const hasKeys = !!keys.length

    if (queryKeys.length && hasKeys) {
        return keys.some((k) => queryKeys.includes(k))
    }

    return hasKeys
}

const toWithQuery = (to, path, queryKeys) => {
    const query = to.query
    const params = to.params

    const withQuery = queryKeys.reduce((keys, key) => {
        if (query[key]) {
            keys[key] = query[key]
        }

        return keys
    }, {})

    return { path, params, query: withQuery }
}

export const persistRouteQuery = (to, from, next) => {
    if (!hasQuery(to) && hasQuery(from, persistentQueries)) {
        next(toWithQuery({ ...to, query: from.query }, to.path, persistentQueries))
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

// router.js
router.beforeEach(persistRouteQuery)
```

There is also [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091380/vue-router-keep-query-parameter-and-use-same-view-for-children) about passing query params to child routes that might help you.

Comment: This works! Thanks Samuel for your help
I missed adding a (base) condition appendQueryParamsToRoute, which led to inifinite redirections. The condition being if TO and FROM are different, then go with the next()